# contact form details is not going to client & admin both by mail even my code seems to be right.please get me out of this

Tags: php

```
   $to = $_POST['email'];
   $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
   $city = $_POST['city'];
   $datetime = $_POST['datetime'];
   $pickarea = $_POST['pickarea'];
   $fulladdress = $_POST['fulladdress'];
   $droparea = $_POST['droparea'];
   $cabquantity = $_POST['cabquantity'];
   $myemail = "designer@aadiweb.com";
   $subject = "Booking Enquiry EasyTrip";
   // Always set content-type when sending HTML email
   $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";

   $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";
   $headers .= 'From:<designer@aadiweb.com>' . "\r\n";
   $headers .= 'Cc:designer@aadiweb.com'. "\r\n";
   $message = "<html><body>";
   $message .= '<h1 style="color:#f40;text-transform: uppercase;">Cab Booking Enquiry</h1>';
   $message .= '<table width="100%"; rules="all" style="border:2px solid #000;" cellpadding="10">';
   $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>" .$to. "</td></tr>";
   $message .= "<tr colspan=2 font='colr:#999999;'><td><strong>Mobile:</strong> <br></td><td>" .$mobile. "</td></tr>";
   $message .= "<tr colspan=2 font='colr:#999999;'><td><strong>City:</strong><br> </td><td>" .$city."</td></tr>";
   $message .= "<tr colspan=2 font='colr:#999999;'><td><strong>Date & Time:<br></strong> </td><td>" .$datetime. "</td></tr>";
   $message .= "<tr colspan=2 font='colr:#999999;'><td><strong>Pick Up Area:</strong> </td><td>" .$pickarea. "</td></tr>";
   $message .= "<tr colspan=2 font='colr:#999999;'><td><strong>Full Address:</strong> </td><td>" .$fulladdress. "</td></tr>";
   $message .= "<tr colspan=2 font='colr:#999999;'><td><strong>Drop Area:</strong> </td><td>" .$droparea. "</td></tr>";
   $message .= "<tr colspan=2 font='colr:#999999;'><td><strong>No. of Cab:</strong> </td><td>" .$cabquantity. "</td></tr>";
   $message .= "</table>";
   $message .= "</body></html>";

   $msg = "Thanks For Your Enquiry in Easy Trip. We Will Contact you soon.";
   $success = mail($myemail, $subject, $message, $headers);
   $success1 = mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers);
   if (isset($success1) && $success1 == true) {
       echo '<script>alert("THANKS For Your Enquiry!!!")</script>';
   } else {
       echo '<script> alert("Try again....) </script>';
   }
```

Comment: why using <br> after every statement

Comment: because i have made an html mail format for better design of received mail @raveenanigam

Comment: oh really !! that's not a good practice at all...whether mail is going to client or admin without message

Comment: Is your project deployed on real live server or it is in your local machine..??

Comment: If you are working on localhost i.e. on your local machine you will need to configure SMTP settings.

Comment: it is live ..@SumitPatil you can check it here -->http://easytripsidcul.com/

Comment: It may possible your headers are not proper. Don't leave From field empty. You can also use `PHPMailer` or 'Sendgrid' for easy mail sending functionality.

Comment: <br> might be giving some issue as you have used it with every statement and its a wrong method of declaring it aswell and you should not use it there

Comment: Not working @SumitPatil

Comment: There is not any <br> tag actually in my code it only shows here in stack flow.Actually this is first time i m asking any question here .so this is my mistake here.@YatinKhullar, sumit

Comment: @Roshan, looks like you have a long way to go to writing proper PHP code. Go back to your learning source, then come back with a proper question about where your code is failing.

Answer (score 0):

Try following headers

```
$headers .= 'To: '.$to. "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: '.$myemail . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Cc: designer@aadiweb.com' . "\r\n";
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'."\r\n";
```

Also remove all `<br>` if it is in your php code.